# Is there a safe way to extend size of a system, boot, active, primary partition in Windows 7 Home premium?

Tags: windows, windows-7, hard-drive, boot, partitioning

[Disk Management System Drives Clip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpxlM.jpg)

Is there a safe way to extend size of a system, boot, active, primary partition in Win7 Home premium?
When I right click on C drive Extend Volume is greyed-out.
This computer is dual boot system with Win7 professional on another drive (E:).
Can I use the Win 7 Prof drive to Extend C: while it is not active without affecting boot for C:?

Comment: Sorry but i added the additional question of: Can I use the Win 7 Prof drive to Extend C: while it is not active without affecting boot for C:?

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the partition using GParted.

1. Go to https://gparted.org/ and download a copy of the ISO
2. Using a tool of your choice, make a bootable flash drive (I recommend Rufus - https://rufus.ie/)
3. Boot to GParted. This will provide you a minimal Linux environment and will launch the GParted application.
4. Using the application, select the partition you want to resize, adjust accordingly, and save.

Of course, there's always a risk to disk data when messing with partition resizing, so be careful.

Comment: Thank You. Looks good I'll give it a try after making a drive image

Comment: You're welcome! Good luck!